# Netbean background editor's?

Tags: netbeans, background, ide

I want to view an image as background on any editor of NetBeans, I could do that on the terminal but I couldn't see any of the same option on NetBeans, is there anyway to do that? Is this possible on Eclipse or another PHP IDE?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. You can set background *color* only (**`Tools -> Options -> Fonts & Colors`** - select `Default` and change color of `Background`).